# Finding Sphere radius given radius of intersecting circle and distance from the top of the sphere

Tags: spheres

How can I find the radius of a sphere if I am given the radius of an intersecting circle- 24cm. The only other unit I am given is the distance from the center of the circle to the  top- most point of the sphere- 32cm. How would I go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture below, you are given that the length in green is $24$ cm and that the length in blue is $32$ cm. You want to calculate the length in red which is the hypotenuse of the triangle with sides $24$ cm and $32$ cm. So the length in red is equal to $(24^2+32^2)^{1/2}=40$ cm.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what is to say that hypotenuse is the radius of the sphere, there is nothing saying the intersecting circle is the midpoint.

Comment: The hypotenuse starts at the center of the sphere and ends at a point in which the circle is intersecting the sphere which must be part of the boundary of the sphere. Therefore, it is the radios of the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a sphere can be given by
$$x^2+y^2=r^2-z^2$$
where  $r^2-z^2$ is the square of radius of any intersecting circle at height $z$ from center of sphere
Hence 
$$r^2-z^2=24^2$$
and $r-z=32$.
Solving simultaneously
\begin{align}
r&=25 \text{ cm (radius of sphere)} \\
z&=-7 \text{ cm}
\end{align}